# How prove this $(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)(2b^2+2a^2-c^2)\le (2a^2+bc)^2$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b,c>0,$ and such $b+c\ge a$,prove that
$$(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)(2b^2+2a^2-c^2)\le (2a^2+bc)^2$$

This problem have many methods? Thank you,

my methods:
$$(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)(2b^2+2a^2-c^2)- (2a^2+bc)^2=-2(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c-b)^2\le 0$$

Have you $Cauchy-Schwarz$ or $AM-GM$ nice methods?

I can  use $AM-GM$ prove 
$$(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)(2b^2+2a^2-c^2)\le \left(\dfrac{4a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}\right)^2$$

Comment: Have you expanded both sides?

Comment: what? Thank you

Comment: use binomial formula to expand the right side and multiply both factors on the left side, put together the same parts and use $b+c \geq a$